# Data usage in case of VPN?

Tags: vpn, openvpn, local-area-network, internet, cisco-vpn

My organization has provided a windows 10 laptop. When I connect to VPN from my home through my home internet and download a file of say 1GB from:

1. Intranet (connected servers)
2. Internet (public)

In both the cases above will the data usage happen from my personal internet connection or since I am connected to organization's VPN, will the data usage happen in organization's internet?

Comment: Anything coming to your home is data usage on your connection. Period.

Comment: `In both the cases above will the data usage happen from my personal internet connection` - Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ask us whether the VPN will not have to send the data over your internet provider link? VPN will send the traffic over an existing connection. It can't make the packets appear at the company without traversing the internet. What VPN does is encrypt the connection, so your internet provider can not spy on you.

Answer (score 2):

Data usage is in your personal network. If you download a file it needs to reach you. VPN is only an encrypted tunnel, not a remote solution.